# Helm Chart available for highly available PostgreSQL on Openshift

Tags: postgresql, openshift, kubernetes-helm, high-availability

I was looking for options to run Postgres HA in production on Openshift.

1. I tried [incubator/patroni](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/patroni)  chart(added sa and scc), but sometimes it runs properly and sometimes lock is not acquired either to master or replica instance of postgres.
   Also there is no way to create automatic schema. Schema needs to be created manually by execing into the pod.
2. Again I tried [stable/postgresql](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql), still there are issues in the helm chart while running it on Openshift
3. I saw some helm charts for production grade setup such as [Zalando Postgres Operator with Patroni](https://github.com/zalando/postgres-operator) and [Crunchy Postgres Operator](https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator) but through single helm chart I am not able to run full setup of highly available postgresql. There are manual steps involved like installing pgo client and connectiong it to psql.

So, is there any postgres highly available helm chart which can be run in production on Openshift with 1 or 2 commands by just changing in values.yaml file.

Answer (score 2):

Bitnami have many interesting helm chart, including one for PostgreSQL:
https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql
For HA: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql-ha

Comment: DO NOT USE THE BITNAMI CHART. As of 14/1/2022, it is still unfit for production, with issues that will cause you severe pain. https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/2610, https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/8062, https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/8237

Comment: as of today 10/12/2023 the first issue is resolved and the other 2 issues seem like feature requests or by version updates may be mitigated. @pkExec can you confirm this?